# Create parameterized Python regular expression pattern

Tags: python, regex

I would like to create regular expression using re module.
But it's unclear how to create a pattern in the similar way of creating a formatted string, e.g.: I need something like

```
myPattern = r'\s*{linehead}'.format(someText)
```

Is this possible?

When I use

`if myPattern.search(l) is not None:`,

I'm getting

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'search'`

Comment: Yes, but you need to use a keyword argument for this pattern:  `myPattern = r'\s*{linehead}'.format(linehead="someText")`

Comment: When I use `if myPattern.search(l) is not None:`, I'm getting 
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'search'`

Comment: or `myPattern = re.compile(r'\s*{linehead}'.format(linehead="someText");` `myPattern.search(l) is not None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, myPattern is simply a string. The 'r' simply tells Python that it's a "raw" string and shouldn't attempt to interpret escaped text.

Once you have your regular expression formatted the way you like it (note, since you named the parameter "linhead", you'll need to identify it in the arguments to `format`:

```
myPattern = r'\s*{linehead}'.format(linehead="someText")
```

You need to make an regular expression object with `re.compile()`.

```
myRegex = re.compile(myPattern)
```

You can now use `myRegex` as you originally intended:

```
if myRegex.search(l) is not None:
    ...
```

Or, you can do this all in one go as @IceArdor suggested:

```
myPattern = re.compile(r'\s*{linehead}'.format(linehead="someText");
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re